# how to add css and js files to Laravel project

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, laravel-5

I need to use JS and CSS files with my Laravel project. This is my JS and CSS file which I hope to add with Laravel blade file:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>jQuery Logo Slider Ticker</title>
    <meta name="description" content="jQuery Logo Slider Ticker by webdesignandsuch.com">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.bxSlider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#slider').bxSlider({
                ticker: true,
                tickerSpeed: 5000,
                tickerHover: true
            });
        });
    </script>

    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

And I have the above JS and CSS files in my Laravel public folder. And I add the above scripts in my Laravel file as following:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <meta name="description" content="jQuery Logo Slider Ticker by webdesignandsuch.com">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    <script src="{{('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('js/jquery.bxSlider.js')}}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#slider').bxSlider({
                ticker: true,
                tickerSpeed: 5000,
                tickerHover: true
            });
        });
    </script>

    <link href="{{asset('css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

But in my Laravel app above, scripts are not working. How can fix it?

Comment: Which error do you get on your console? (Ps. I think you should research about Elixir https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir )

Comment: `asset('js/jquery.bxSlider.js')` will look for `jquery.bxSlider.js` in the `js` subdirectory of your default asset directory (probably public?) but you said that file is in the public directory.

Comment: **asset('js/jquery.bxSlider.js')** files in the public->js folder

Comment: No, any error not running above slider